# Problem with collectionView that content mct: expander

Tags: c#, mvvm, maui, expander, maui-community-toolkit

I'm working on MAUI C# application desktop.
I need to put many expander in collectionView.

Here is my code in view :

```
 <CollectionView x:Name="question" ItemsSource="{Binding Audit.Questions}" IsVisible="false" WidthRequest="800">
     <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Question">
             <VerticalStackLayout>
                 <mct:Expander x:Name="questionz" IsExpanded="False">
                     <mct:Expander.Header>
                         <Grid BackgroundColor="LightGray" Padding="10" HeightRequest="100" MinimumHeightRequest="100">
                             <Label Text="{Binding Intitule}" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="0"></Label>
                             <Image  Source="exclamation_mark.png"
                                     HeightRequest="20" 
                                     TranslationX="380"
                                     ToolTipProperties.Text="{Binding RappelJuridique}"/>
                         </Grid>
                     </mct:Expander.Header>
                     <mct:Expander.Content>
                         <StackLayout 
                             MinimumHeightRequest="150">
                             <HorizontalStackLayout
                                 RadioButtonGroup.GroupName="questionAnswer"
                                 
                                 >
                                 <RadioButton GroupName="questionAnswer"
                                              x:Name="conforme"
                                              Content="Conforme"
                                              Value="1"
                                              CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
                                 </RadioButton>
                                 <RadioButton GroupName="questionAnswer"
                                              x:Name="nonConforme"
                                              Content="Non conforme"
                                              Value="0"
                                              CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
                                 </RadioButton>
                                 <RadioButton GroupName="questionAnswer"
                                              x:Name="nonFait"
                                              Content="non Fait"
                                              Value=""
                                              CheckedChanged="RadioButton_CheckedChanged">
                                 </RadioButton>
                             </HorizontalStackLayout>
                             <Entry Placeholder="Commentaire" Text="{Binding Commentaire}" HeightRequest="100" ></Entry>
                         </StackLayout>
                     </mct:Expander.Content>
                 </mct:Expander>
             </VerticalStackLayout>
         </DataTemplate>
     </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
 </CollectionView>
```

The problem is that expanders have weird behavior wheb I click on the expander Header:

[image]

*Edit the weird behavior is when I click on a header expander in the list there is blank expander Content or I click on an expander header at the bottom of the list and I open a expander.content on the top.

It's like every thing is ok at the top of the list and the behavior change at the end.
Or this kind of problem:
[image]

Did someone can help me ?

Thanks for your time

Comment: please describe what the specific "weird behavior" is

Comment: Thanks for your anwers I put more details

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this problem for desktop on my side.   You can try to update your visual studio to the latest version and use the newer version of nugets for your app.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Visual studio and nuget are in the last version

Comment: I think the problem comme from the border of the app it's like the opening of the expander is block by the general border of the app

Comment: What's `the border of the app` ?  How can we reproduce this problem? Could you please post the steps of reproducing this problem?

Comment: When I load 18 expander in the collectionView I have this problem. The app is open in a window and the window have 4 edges/borders Ithink the last expanders are blocked by the bottom edge. apologize my english

Answer (score 0):

If I added more items to the CollectionView, I could find there are some issues about displaying and hiding the content of the `Expander` on window platform.

And I found there are some similar issues about this, you can check them here:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/9023

https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/18078

In fact, you can also create a new issue about this problem to raise the level of the relevant issues.

Thanks for your support for Maui and feedback.